# Could not pass list object into template bottle

Tags: python, web, python-2.7, bottle

I have some problem with bottle template. I can not pass python list to template. My code is below:

```
@route('/'):
def home():
    return template('home', var=['item1', 'item2'])
```

And this is home.tpl:

```
<html>
   <ul>
       #for item in var:
         <li>{{item}}</li>
       #end
   </ul>
</html>
```

I think it work but exception not defined variable 'item' throwed.
Could please tell me where my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottle template syntax uses `%`, *not* `#` to mark python(ish) blocks:

```html
<html>
   <ul>
       %for item in var:
         <li>{{item}}</li>
       %end
   </ul>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through the list in the reverse order, the following template will work.

```
<html>
     <ul>
         %for i in range(len(var)-1,-1,-1):
             <li>{{var[i]}}</li>
         %end
     </ul>
</html>
```